# Center Set of Controls in Bootstrap 3 Row With Proper Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I am new to web development, particularly CSS and Bootstrap.  I am struggling to center the set of 5 items in a Bootstrap row.  Here is what I have:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center" style="border:2px solid green">
        <div style="display:inline-block;float:none;vertical-align:top;margin-top:8px">My Label</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1"style="display:inline-block;float:none">
            <input class="form-control" type="number"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="width:2%;display:inline-block;float:none"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1"style="display:inline-block;float:none">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" role="button">Button1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2"style="display:inline-block;float:none">
            <input class="form-control" type="number"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="width:2%;display:inline-block;float:none"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1"style="display:inline-block;float:none">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" role="button">Button2</button>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

For the most part, it gives me the result I want in Firefox and Chrome.  The controls are spaced a little and it is responsive -- the white space shrinks while the controls grow (in % of screen) as the screen gets smaller.  Control widths are controlled via Bootstrap col-*-# classes.  Though, IE seems to align the buttons at the bottom of the row for some reason. I'm not sure why.

Aside from defining custom CSS classes instead of style attributes, is this the correct/best way to achieve the result that I want?  Or, is there a better way to do this in CSS or Bootstrap?  It seems hackish to have to use vertical-align and margin to get the label to line up.  Also, I started out using form elements and classes.  But, that kept making things worse.  What is the benefit of using the form element or downside to not using it?

I read numerous similar posts.  But they all seemed to have something different enough that the solutions seemed to not fit what I am doing.  I have a set of controls that I want centered as a unit.  I do not want to simply snap them to the 12-column Bootstrap grid.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lktd719/)

Answer (score 0):

You still can use a custom class when you need it :

```
.classname {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I pointed out that I knew defining a class was better than leaving that repeated style inline.  I want to know if my approach in general is the right way.  I did not use <form form-inline> and form-group classes because it seemed to mess everything up.  Also, vertical-align:middle on the My Label div did not help.  In fact middle pushed it lower than bottom which is really weird (in Firefox).